Why did Lenny decide to follow Jimmy's instructions and meet Natalie?
In Memento, after he killed Jimmy, he saw in Jimmy's clothes' pocket a note that said to go to Natalie when he was at the tattoo store.
So why did he follow that note; I thought he made a rule to only trust his hand writing?

Is it possible he hadn't made that rule yet?

But in one of the black and white scene which happended before jimmy's death , we saw Lenny talking to an unknown person that he only trusted his own hand writing while he was telling his story about sammy jenkins so he must have that rule way before that

The rule about only trusting his own handwriting is in regards to what he considers a trustworthy fact. Such as “this is my car”, or “he is the one”. The note in his pocket was not stating a fact that he assumed to be true; it was just an invite to go somewhere. If the note turned out to be untrustworthy, all that he’s lost is the wasted time going to the bar. He’s not making any important decisions or assumptions based on that note.

that's a nice perspective , I just assume he always burn stuff he doesn't want to remember or unimportant so the fact the paper still there mean its important and should be remember
